# Numeric combination

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n$ be an positive integer and $\sigma = (a_1, \dots, a_n)$ a permutation of $\{1, \dots, n\}$. The cadence number of $\sigma$ is the number of maximal decrescent blocks.

For example, if $n = 6$ and $\sigma = (4, 2, 1, 5, 6, 3)$, then the cadence number of $\sigma$ is $3$, because $\sigma$ has $3$ maximal decrescent blocks: $(4, 2, 1)$, $(5)$ and $(6, 3)$. Note that $(4, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$ are decrescent, but not maximal, because they are already contained in $(4, 2, 1)$.

Compute the sum of the cadence number of every permutation of $\{1, \dots, n\}$.

What I thought: for these sequences, the mean value is likely to coincide with the median value

Comment: Suggestion: When trying to wrap your head around a problem like this, do the first few small examples, with $n=1$, $2$, $3$ and $4$, and look for patterns. You can also test your idea about the mean and the median.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to try induction. Where do you place the largest number? When will the number of decrescent block change? Stay the same?

Comment: Does (132) have cadence 2 or, because it is the same permutation as (321), does it have cadence 1?

Comment: @S.Dolan 132) have cadence 2: the blocks are (1) and (3, 2)

Comment: Good - that's what I used for the answer. There might well be lot's more about cadence to investigate.

Comment: @S.Dolan Correct?

Comment: I assume the last $n$ on the LHS is a typo. I had conjectured this myself but found the other proof before I could see how to prove this result.

Comment: By the way, have you seen how to prove this result? It's actually quite easy and gives a 'better' proof than the one I posted. In particular it proves your original conjecture - there is a nice symmetry so that the mean and median are indeed equal.

Comment: @S.Dolan Can you show me? Without wishing to take your time.

Comment: OK. I'll add another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternate method**

In any arrangement $a_1 a_1 ...  a_n$ insert the appropriate $<$ or $>$ sign between each successive pairs of $a_i$.

Let there be $l$  less than signs and $g$ greater than signs. Then $l+g=n-1$ and the cadence number is $l+1$.

Similarly, the reversed arrangement has cadence number $g+1$.

The sum of the cadence numbers is therefore $l+g+2=n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming that the cadence number is for arrangements of $1,2,...,n$ rather than for the underlying permutations (see my earlier comment) then the expected value of the cadence number  is $C(n)=\frac{n+1}{2}.$

The number $1$ has $n$ equally likely positions in the arrangement.

Suppose $1$ is in the $1$st position. Then the expected cadence number is $1+C(n-1)$.

Suppose $1$ is in the $i$th position, $i>1$. Then the expected cadence number is $C(i-1)+C(n-i)$.

Proceeding inductively, we have $$nC(n)=1+2\sum_1^{n-1} C(i)=\sum_1^{n} i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ and therefore $$C(n)=\frac{n+1}{2}.$$